# Vue non reactive data available on instance

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, reactive-programming, vuex

I want to store object in vue, it should be available for entire instance and not be reactive. Normally (with reactive) I would use 'data' like this:

```
new Vue({
  data: myObject
})
```

But in fact myObject don't need to change so I think making it reactive is bad. Is there any method to do this?

Comment: Reference it globally? `window.myObject = myObject`

Comment: I was thinking more about vue solution. I want to use it only in vue instance, I don't want littering global namespace

Comment: You might want to be looking into Vuex.

Comment: @RuChernChong I am using vuex already. Any more details?

Comment: @Bogdan set your `myObject` into the Vuex *state* and don't provide any mutators

Comment: @Bogdan not that I could think of now. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Vue Instance Properties.

> There may be data/utilities you’d like to use in many components, but you don’t want to pollute the global scope. In these cases, you can make them available to each Vue instance by defining them on the prototype:

```
Vue.prototype.$appName = 'My App'
```

Now $appName is available on all Vue instances, even before creation. If we run:

```
new Vue({
  beforeCreate: function () {
    console.log(this.$appName)
  }
})
```

Reference: [Link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html#Simple-Example)

**Or**

You can use Vuex state for that data property and define mutations only if you want to change the value.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using Vuex, simply set your data into the store's *state* and don't provide any mutations to keep it read-only.

For example...

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: myObject
})

// assuming you've added Vue.use(Vuex) if using a module system
new Vue({
  // el, data, etc
  store
})
```

then your Vue instance or components can access

```
this.$store.state.somePropertyOfMyObject
```